# Order of a symmetry group of a quadrilateral

Tags: group-theory

I am studying group theory. When reading text on the theory part, I do not feel difficult to understand the concepts, like what is a group, or what is Cauchy's Theorem. However, I often find it difficult to do problems, like the one below.

> Let $Q$ be a plane quadrilateral. Show that its group $G (Q )$ of symmetries has order at most
>   $8$. For each n in the set $\{ 1, 2,..., 8\}$, either give an example of a quadrilateral $Q$ with $G(Q)$
>   of order $n$, or show that no such quadrilateral can exist.

What I find difficult is the following:

1. I cannot decide which theorem is related to the question, and when I start doing the problem, I just think of examples, like a rhombus has a symmetry group of order 4.
2. How to prove that for a particular value of $n$, say $n=7$, no such symmetry group exists?
3. How to relate theorems I've learnt to problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not every problem can be solved by simply invoking a theorem. Some of them require reasoning from the basics.

Note that a symmetry will be completely determined by where it sends the vertices of the $Q$. Let the vertices be $A,B,C,D$  and edges $AB$, $BC$, $CD$, $DA$. There are 4 possiblities for where a symmetry can send $A$, namely $A,B,C,D$. Call the vertex where $A$ is sent $X$. Once we've determined where $A$ goes, there is only one possible place that $C$ can go, and that is to the only vertex that is not adjacent to $X$, because a symmetry must preserve edges. After that there are two possiblities for where we may send $B$, so there are at most $8$ possibilities.

Clearly if $Q$ is scalene the symmetry group has order $1$. For an isosceles trapezoid with two different base lengths the symmetry group has order $2$. For a rectangle that is not a square the symmetry group has order $4$, and for a square the symmetry group has order $8$ (you should verify all of these).

The symmetry group of an arbitrary $Q$ can be seen as a subgroup of the symmetry group of a square where some symmetries aren't allowed. Lagrange's theorem then implies that the order must divide $8$, hence no other orders are possible (here is an example where a theorem can be applied).

Comment: How could I argue that the symmetry group of an arbitrary $Q$ being a subgroup of the symmetry group of a square?

Comment: @Rescy argue that a bijection between the two sets of vertices preserving edges induces an injective homomorphism of symmetry groups.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f$ be a symmetry of the plane quadrilateral $A,B,C,D$ $f$ sends a diagonal to a diagonal, if $(AC)$ is the diagonal through $A$ and $C$,

$f((AC))=f((AC))$ In this case we have:

$Id$

$f(A)=A, f(C)=C, f(B)=D$

$f(A)=C, f(B)=B$

$f(A)=C, f(B)=D$

If $f((AC))=f((BD))$ we have:

$f(A)=B, f(C)=D, f(B)=A, f(D)=C$

$f(A)=B, f(C)=D, f(B)=C, f(D)=A$

$f(A)=D, f(C)=B, f(B)=A, f(D)=C$

$f(A)=D, f(C)=B, f(B)=C, f(D)=A$

The group of symmetries of $A,B,C,D$ is a subgroup of the symmetric group $S_4$ (since it is contained in the group of permutations of $\{A,B,C,D\}$) which has 24 elements, thus Lagrange theorem implies that its order divides 24 and thus can't be 7.

Answer (score 0):

1. Show that $G(Q)^+$ (the isometries of determinant $1$) acts $\textit{freely}$ on the set of vertices of $Q$. Deduce from this that $|G(Q)^+|$ will divide $4$.
2. Show that either $G(Q)^+=G(Q)$ or $[G(Q):G(Q)^+]=2$ (hint use the group morphism $det:G(Q)\rightarrow \{\pm 1\}$).
3. Deduce from 1 and 2 that $|G(Q)|\leq 8$, and $|G(Q)|$ is a power of $2$ (in particular the rectangle does not have $6$ symmetries).

   4. For $1$, $2$, $4$, $8$ give a corresponding quadrilateral.

Comment: I haven't learnt what is meant by 'free', and do not know about group morphism det.

Comment: @Rescy_, a free action is an action for which the stablizers are all trivial (you need to know what "a group action" is, to understand this...),det is the determinant.